How can I import from the root of a package with multiple `rootDirs`?
Let's say I have a monorepo with a package app and a package lib:
root/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  packages/
    app/
      package.json
      ts.config.json
      App.tsx
    lib/
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
      src/
        components/
          ComponentA.tsx
        utils.ts

Let's say I want to be able to import directly from lib without specifying full paths. I can do that by use of an index file in lib/src and a path alias in app/tsconfig.json:
// packages/lib/src/index.ts
export {default as ComponentA} from './components/CompnentA'
export {someUtil} from './utils'

// packages/app/package.json
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "lib": "*"
  }
}

// packages/app/tsconfig.json
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "lib/*": ["../lib/src/*"]
   }
  },
  "references": [
    {"path": "../lib"}
  ]
}

// packages/lib/tsconfig.json
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "type": "composite",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}

Ok, cool -- now I can do this:
// App.tsx
import {ComponentA, someUtil} from 'lib'

So far so good. But say I want to have multiple root directories in lib/tsconfig.json (perhaps because I want to use separate src/ and test/ folders, but that's not relevant here):
// packages/lib/tsconfig.json
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["./src", "./test/"],
    "type": "composite",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*", "test/**/*"
  ]
}

From the Typescript docs, this looks tantalizingly like a supported use case. But having multiple rootDirs in lib breaks the package-level import in App.tsx:
// App.tsx

// still works OK
import ComponentA from 'lib/components/ComponentA'
import {someUtil} from 'lib/utils'

// still works OK
import {Component A, someUtil} from 'lib/index'

// ✗ doesn't work anymore :(
import {ComponentA, someUtil} from 'lib'  


(I see the same issue if I use rootDir: "." instead of rootDirs: ["./src", "./test"] in lib/tsconfig.json.)
How can I make the root-level import work when the lib rootDir is not ./src?

Install the package as a dependency where you're trying to use it. It sounds like you might want to use a monorepo to accomplish this. Look into turborepo, lerna or pnpm workspaces.

@Andrew it's a monorepo -- I added some details to clarify that.
